# When using Firebase login, it is always automatically logged in

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, android-viewmodel

I have implemented login using `firebase`.

When you log in from the `login fragment`, you go to the next screen.

However, if you restart the app after logging in once, you are always automatically logged in. That is, the app always starts on the next screen.

What I was expecting was to be logged in after pressing the 'login button'.

However, you will be automatically logged in without pressing the button.

I'm working around this temporarily by forcing `signOut()` and setting the value of `user` to `null` to solve this.

What causes these problems?

---

**LoginFragment**

```
class LogInFragment : Fragment() {
    private var _binding : FragmentLogInBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private val loginVM: LoginViewModel by activityViewModels()
    lateinit var mFirebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var mDatabaseRef: DatabaseReference
    private lateinit var savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
    
    companion object {
        const val LOGIN_SUCCESSFUL: String = "LOGIN_SUCCESSFUL"
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater,
                          container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        _binding = FragmentLogInBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("LightWeight")

        binding.btnRegister.setOnClickListener { view ->
            view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_logInFragment_to_registerFragment)
        }

        binding.btnLogin.setOnClickListener { _ ->
            var email: String = binding.etId.text.toString()
            var pwd: String = binding.etPwd.text.toString()
            loginVM.login(email, pwd)
        }

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        savedStateHandle = findNavController().previousBackStackEntry!!.savedStateHandle
        savedStateHandle.set(LOGIN_SUCCESSFUL, false)

        loginVM.authenticationState.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { test ->
            when(test) {
                LoginViewModel.AuthenticationState.AUTHENTICATED -> {
                    savedStateHandle.set(LOGIN_SUCCESSFUL, true)
                    findNavController().popBackStack()
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
                else ->
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**LoginViewModel**

```
class LoginViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val repository: AuthenticationRepository = AuthenticationRepository()

    val authenticationState = repository.getUserData().map { user ->
        if (user != null) {
            AuthenticationState.AUTHENTICATED
        } else {
            AuthenticationState.UNAUTHENTICATED
        }
    }

    sealed class AuthenticationState {
        object AUTHENTICATED: AuthenticationState()
        object UNAUTHENTICATED : AuthenticationState()
    }


    fun login(email: String, pwd: String) {
        repository.login(email, pwd)
    }
}
```

**AuthRepository**

```
class AuthenticationRepository {
    private val databaseRef: DatabaseReference =
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("LightWeight")
    private val firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    private val userLiveData: MutableLiveData<FirebaseUser?> = MutableLiveData<FirebaseUser?>()

    fun getUserData() : MutableLiveData<FirebaseUser?> {
//        firebaseAuth.signOut()  // temporary
//        userLiveData.postValue(null) // temporary
        return userLiveData
    }
    fun login(email: String, pwd: String) {
        firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pwd)
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if(task.isSuccessful) {
                    userLiveData.postValue(firebaseAuth.currentUser)
                }
                else {

                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Firebase Authentication automatically stores the user credentials in local storage, and restores that when the app is restarted. There is no way to change this behavior.

Comment: Since you are using Kotlin, I think that this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-an-android-app-using-multiple-firebase-products-in-kotlin-16aade81ffec) will help. Or if you want to see Jetpack Compose in action, check this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-handle-firebase-authentication-in-clean-architecture-using-jetpack-compose-e9929c0e31f8).